# Python + webkit + os.fork()

Tags: python, webkit, webview, fork

I have some troubles trying to callback webkit functions from a child process. This code are meant to load background resources and insert them by javascript asynchronously. I need to callback javascript functions once the resource is loaded while keep the interface working. I tried to sync threads throught pipes, but the while(1) polling in the main thread (to read the pipe) blocks the interface the same way as if the resource were loaded in the main. If I callback the webview.execute_script with javascript from the child process it does nothing except when I feed it with an alert like funcion, then breaks :S

Example given:

```
    import pygtk
    pygtk.require("2.0")

    import gtk,webkit,os

    class Browser:
        def __init__(self):
            self.window = gtk.Window()
            #self.window.set_decorated(False)
            self.window.set_default_size(800, 600)
            vbox = gtk.VBox()
            self.scroll_window = gtk.ScrolledWindow()
            self.webview = webkit.WebView()
            self.webview.set_transparent(True)
            self.window.add(self.webview)
            self.window.show_all()
            self.webview.load_uri("http://google.es");
            self.error();

        def error(self):
            child_pid = os.fork()
            if child_pid == 0:
                self.webview.execute_script("""
                    alert(1);
                """)
                os._exit(0)

        def noerror(self):
            self.webview.execute_script("""
                alert(1);
            """)

    if __name__ == "__main__":
        browser = Browser()
        try:
          while True:
              gtk.main_iteration()
        except:
          gtk.main_quit()
          print "BAILING OUT!"
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

webkit is not thread-safe.

See: http://markmail.org/message/4dwft6s6g6ptavj6

Comment: Oh!, I see, is there any method of comunication between threads that doent need polling in python? The problem is the newbie in python I am. Im searching for somethig like the event-listeners in javascript, so I can declase a listener, do stuff in a thread and call the listener in main. Is that possible? Thanks so much